# Hudson configuration to run QTP

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, qtp

I am trying to run a QTP test from Hudson as Hudson gives a way to run multiple QTP scripts on multiple slaves at the same time.
As a proof of concept, I need to to run one QTP scripts from Hudson and produce the results in Hudson using HTML publisher plugin.

So far I have done following:
1. I have written a QTP script for proof of concept.
2. I have written a VB Script code and put that in a .vbs file in c drive. This code will invoke QTP and pull the required test on QTP, execute it and save the HTML result in a specified location.
3. I have created a .bat file in c drive which will run the .vbs file (.vbs file will invoke QTP and run the test).
4. I have created a project in Hudson and only Master is running the build.

I am facing difficulties in configuring the project. Under Build section I have chosen "Execute Windows Batch Command".
I want to know what command I need to specify to run the .bat file as above?

Could someone please help?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: were u able to configure Hudson With Qtp

Answer (score 0):

`cmd /C C:\<path-to-your-bat>`

You are not setting up your build well, though - everything is hard-coded. You need flexibility as far as paths are concerned. I hope you'll fix it after you are done with your POC.

Comment: I tried above code but Hudson is unable to run the .bat file. Any other clue where I am wrong? I have used command as                                                                      cmd /C C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\QTPStart.bat

Comment: What does the log say? Also, how are you running Hudson?

Comment: I am running Hudson as windows service through Tomcat and running the URL as http://localhost:8080/ to run Hudson. Which log you are talking about and where can I see this log?

Comment: (1) To locate the log for the last build: enter `http://localhost:8080/job/<your-job-name>/lastBuild/console` (2) Try running Hudson stand-alone and not as a service, but in the foreground with `java -jar hudson.war --httpPort=8080`.

Comment: the console output is as follows: Started by user anonymous
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update; build not configured with trigger: QTP Test Multi Configuration #19
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: please add 'echo ON' in your batch script as well as in your batch build step and post the log again.